# Adding javascript to over 200 html files, easiest way?

Tags: javascript, html, css, adsense

I was wondering the easiest way to go about adding some javascript adsense code into 200 or more existing html files that serve as a picture gallery.

I've read some solutions such as putting the javascript into a php file and then inserting a link to the php file but so far the HTML doesn't permit that unless I use a placeholder perhaps? That is not to familiar to me.

The other way in which I was thinking to ad this code is by a separate CSS stylesheet, that I can link to right from the index.html .... any ideas?

Comment: JavaScript in a CSS file? That is not possible. And over 200 html files..

Comment: Are you using a server-side language or just plain HTML files?

Comment: From Serverfault: [How to inject HTML code into every delivered HTML page?](http://serverfault.com/questions/46449/how-to-inject-html-code-into-every-delivered-html-page)

Comment: What development tools are you using ? For example in Visual Studio there is a find and replace in Files. What Operating system are you using as there is ways of doing this in Unix. I.e Find </body> and replace it with a blah </body>

Comment: Many IDE-s support Find/Replace operations for multiple files. [Sublime text for example](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html)

Comment: Now is probably a good time to think about how to refactor your code. Using 200+ files for a picture gallery sounds wrong. Using an database you only need one or two files...

Comment: I am using just plain html files.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a programming problem. This sounds more like something that you should use powershell or some over tool to do.

Comment: Actually when you use Picasa 3 to assemble a photo gallery, the program itself automatically generated the 200 html files for me, using one photo per html page as being displayed. It would have generated 500 html files, if I had 500 photos in the gallery.

Comment: Here's the gallery, on the main page, I manually added the adsense code, but would like to automatically generate the same without having to go to add it to all the individual pages that you would see upon viewing the individual photos. And yes, I do agree that displaying a photo gallery like this is at best least efficient with the fancier tools available.     http://hamiltonhistorical.com/photo_gallery/Gallery/

Comment: @RichBaxter With your current solution you need to regenerate all files if you add a new picture or want to do some other change. It can be refactored into one php file without database connection if you don't have access to that. Can you run php on your server?

Comment: Yes, I can run php on the server.

Comment: @RichBaxter Please add your email on your profile, because your question will soon be deleted for being off topic.

Comment: @RichBaxter I added an answer with a script that you could use instead of having 200+ html-files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could use php to read all the files to string, locate the closing body tag `</body>` and replace it with the script tag  and `</body>` and rewrite back to file.

Or do same in an IDE that can read whole directoreis and find/replace.

Save backup of all before starting

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer, I'll give it a try! And of course backup as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer to the question you asked but it could help you in the future.

There is a big problem when you create a separate file for each image. You just found out how painful it can be to edit all those files. There are better ways to implement it. A better way is to use some kind of template. Then you only need to edit the template and then regenerate the files.

But you can skip that to and let a script dynamically create the pages when someone asks for them.

Below you find a simple php-script that I created for you, that should get you started. You just add all the images to the array $images, and it will dynamically create the pages you need.

```
<?php
  // Add all images here. Asumes that thumbnails and full size images
  // has the same name and is placed in "thumbnails/" and "images/"
  $images = Array(
    Array('src'=>'hamilton_historical_photos_1.jpg', 'title' => 'Title of photo 1'),
    Array('src'=>'hamilton_historical_photos_2.jpg', 'title' => 'Title of photo 2'),
    Array('src'=>'hamilton_historical_photos_4.jpg', 'title' => 'Title of photo 4')
  );


  // Using a seach-variable of 'image' to show a specific image'
  // Note: Arrays are indexed from 0, but we want to be friendly and show
  // the first image when image=1. Therefore 1 must be subtracted to get the
  // real index.
  $idx = @$_GET['image'] -1;

  // Get information about the image. If the index is wrong we don't get
  // any information. That is used later in the code when testing if
  // $image has a value or not.
  $image = @$images[ $idx ];

  // Default title
  $title = "Township of Hamilton Historical photos";

  // If an image was found, add that to the title.
  if ($image) $title .= " - " . $image['title'];


?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2656154241161799";
    /* 160x600, created 1/31/09 */
    google_ad_slot = "6877855916";
    google_ad_width = 160;
    google_ad_height = 600;
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .thumbnails {
      text-align:center;
    }
    .thumbnails img {
      vertical-align:middle;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  // Get number of images
  $max = count($images);

  // Test if an image was seleted, if so show that image.
  if ($image) {
    echo "<div class='textbg'>$title</div>";

    echo "<div class='textreg'>";

    $sep = " | ";

    // 'First' should be a link if we aren't on the first image
    $label = "First";
    if ($idx == 0) echo $label; else echo "<a href='?image=1'>$label</a>";
    echo $sep;

    // 'Previous Picture' should be a link if we aren't on the first image
    $label = "Previous Picture";
    if ($idx == 0) echo $label; else echo "<a href='?image=" . $idx . "'>$label</a>";
    echo $sep;

    // 'Next Picture' should be a link if we aren't on the last image
    $label = "Next Picture";
    if (($idx+1) == $max) echo $label; else echo "<a href='?image=" . ($idx +2) . "'>$label</a>";
    echo $sep;

    // 'Last' should be a link if we aren't on the last image
    $label = "Last";
    if (($idx+1) == $max) echo $label; else echo "<a href='?image=" . $max . "'>$label</a>";
    echo $sep;

    echo "<a href='?'>Thumbnails</a>";

    echo "</div>";

    echo "<hr size='1'>";

    echo "<a href='?'>" .
      "<img " .
        "src='images/" . htmlspecialchars($image['src']) . "' " .
        "title='" . htmlspecialchars($image['title']) . "'" .
      ">" .
      "</a>";

  } else {
    // Showing thumbnails
    echo "<div class='textbg'>Twp of Hamilton Historical Pictures</div>";
    echo "<span class='auto-style2'><a href='http://www.hamiltonhistorical.com'>Hamilton Historical Website</a></span>";
    echo "<span class='textbg'> ($max images) </span>";
    echo "<hr size='1'>";


    echo "<div class='thumbnails'>";
    echo "<div class='textreg'>Click a picture to see a larger view.</div>";
    foreach ($images as $idx => $image) {
      $idx = $idx + 1;
      echo "<a href='?image=$idx'>" .
        "<img " .
          "src='thumbnails/" . htmlspecialchars($image['src']) . "' " .
          "title='" . htmlspecialchars($image['title']) . "'" .
        ">" .
        "</a>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that's awesome. Double thumbs up!